# Regarding Lebesgue measurability of a set used in Scattering Theory (problem 10 Reed Simon Vol. 3)

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

In Theorem XI.3 of Scattering Theory by Reed and Simon, the authors define two sets, $N_{+}$ and $N_{-}$, as follows:
\begin{align*}
\ddot{r}(t) &=  F(r(t)) \\
N_{+} &= \{\langle q, v \rangle | \overline{\lim_{t \to +\infty}} |r_{q,v}(t)| < \infty\} \\
N_{-} &= \{\langle q, v \rangle | \overline{\lim_{t \to -\infty}} |r_{q,v}(t)| < \infty\}
\end{align*}
Here $F = -\nabla V$ and $V \to 0$ as $r \to 0$, furthermore F obeys some constraint regarding boundedness and decaying conditions namely:
\begin{align}
|F(r)| &\leq C|r|^{-a}  \tag{3a} \\
|F(r) - F(r')| &\leq D_R |r-r'|, \quad |r-r'|<1, \quad |r|<R \tag{3b} \\
|F(r)| &\leq Cr^{-a}, \quad \alpha > 2 \tag{4a} \\
|F(x) - F(y)| &\leq Dr^{-\beta} |x-y|, \quad \text{for all } |x|, |y| > r \text{ and } \beta >2  \tag{4b}
\end{align}

The theorem deals with asymptotic completeness in two-body classical particle scattering. The sets N+ and N- represent the collection of initial conditions (position and velocity) for which the solutions of the classical equations of motion remain bounded as t approaches positive or negative infinity, respectively.
I'm not very keen on measurability of sets and I just know the theoretical basis but I'd really appreciate if someone could provide a proof that $N_{+}$ and $N_{-}$ are measurable sets since I wouldn't even know where to start from.
Thank you in avance.

Comment: I think it depends on how $r_{q,v}$ depends on $q$ and $v$.  If $r_{q,v}(t)$ is a continuous function of $t$, then that $\limsup$ can be taken using only rational $t$.